# Why does TYPO3 Composer Helper (typo3/full) installs TYPO3 Core 8.7?

Tags: composer-php, typo3, typo3-9.x

I want to install TYPO3 9 with all core extensions, so I can snap the needed extensions for my project.

I used https://get.typo3.org/misc/composer/helper to install TYPO3 9 with all core-exensions.

I clicked on typo3/full and got

```
composer require typo3/cms-about typo3/cms-adminpanel typo3/cms-backend typo3/cms-belog typo3/cms-beuser typo3/cms-core typo3/cms-extbase typo3/cms-extensionmanager typo3/cms-feedit typo3/cms-felogin typo3/cms-filelist typo3/cms-filemetadata typo3/cms-fluid typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content typo3/cms-form typo3/cms-frontend typo3/cms-impexp typo3/cms-indexed-search typo3/cms-info typo3/cms-install typo3/cms-linkvalidator typo3/cms-lowlevel typo3/cms-opendocs typo3/cms-recordlist typo3/cms-recycler typo3/cms-redirects typo3/cms-reports typo3/cms-rsaauth typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor typo3/cms-scheduler typo3/cms-seo typo3/cms-setup typo3/cms-sys-action typo3/cms-sys-note typo3/cms-t3editor typo3/cms-taskcenter typo3/cms-tstemplate typo3/cms-viewpage typo3/cms-workspaces
```

But in my console I got the following error by typo3/cms-core 8.7 … don't understand why

```
$ composer require typo3/cms-about typo3/cms-adminpanel typo3/cms-backend typo3/cms-belog typo3/cms-beuser typo3/cms-core typo3/cms-extbase typo3/cms-extensionmanager typo3/cms-feedit typo3/cms-felogin typo3/cms-filelist typo3/cms-filemetadata typo3/cms-fluid typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content typo3/cms-form typo3/cms-frontend typo3/cms-impexp typo3/cms-indexed-search typo3/cms-info typo3/cms-install typo3/cms-linkvalidator typo3/cms-lowlevel typo3/cms-opendocs typo3/cms-recordlist typo3/cms-recycler typo3/cms-redirects typo3/cms-reports typo3/cms-rsaauth typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor typo3/cms-scheduler typo3/cms-seo typo3/cms-setup typo3/cms-sys-action typo3/cms-sys-note typo3/cms-t3editor typo3/cms-taskcenter typo3/cms-tstemplate typo3/cms-viewpage typo3/cms-workspaces

Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-about
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-adminpanel
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-backend
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-belog
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-beuser
Using version ^8.7 for typo3/cms-core
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-extbase
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-extensionmanager
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-feedit
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-felogin
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-filelist
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-filemetadata
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-fluid
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-form
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-frontend
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-impexp
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-indexed-search
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-info
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-install
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-linkvalidator
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-lowlevel
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-opendocs
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-recordlist
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-recycler
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-redirects
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-reports
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-rsaauth
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-scheduler
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-seo
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-setup
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-sys-action
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-sys-note
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-t3editor
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-taskcenter
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-tstemplate
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-viewpage
Using version ^9.5 for typo3/cms-workspaces
./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - typo3/cms-about v9.5.5 requires typo3/cms-core 9.5.5 -> satisfiable by typo3/cms-core[v9.5.5] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - typo3/cms-about v9.5.4 requires typo3/cms-core 9.5.4 -> satisfiable by typo3/cms-core[v9.5.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - typo3/cms-about v9.5.3 requires typo3/cms-core 9.5.3 -> satisfiable by typo3/cms-core[v9.5.3] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - typo3/cms-about v9.5.2 requires typo3/cms-core 9.5.2 -> satisfiable by typo3/cms-core[v9.5.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - typo3/cms-about v9.5.1 requires typo3/cms-core 9.5.1 -> satisfiable by typo3/cms-core[v9.5.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - typo3/cms-about v9.5.0 requires typo3/cms-core 9.5.0 -> satisfiable by typo3/cms-core[v9.5.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for typo3/cms-about ^9.5 -> satisfiable by typo3/cms-about[v9.5.0, v9.5.1, v9.5.2, v9.5.3, v9.5.4, v9.5.5].


Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.
```

TYPO3 installs the typo3/cms-core version 8.7, but I don't know why. Does someone know whats wrong here?

I think the requirement of one extension is false?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was my mistake.

I tried to install TYPO3 9.5 with PHP 7.1 only on my local machine. After I started a ddev with PHP 7.2 everything works like expected.

I hope that helps others who get the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

Did you choose the right TYPO3 version?

You will get other packages and configuration options if you select a corresponding version here in advance.

Currently you can choose between the following versions:

- Any Version
- TYPO3 10.2
- TYPO3 9.5 LTS
- TYPO3 8.7 LTS